# mongodb nodejs multiple insert issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to import a table from mysql to mongodb straight without any schema changes.

I wrote a small node script for that and my issue is with the way i implemented it.

Maybe I hit some limit of using mongo db insert limit while using it inside a loop.
I think this problem would not have had come if it was in reverse (maybe not! )

So here's the thing.
The row in the mysql table is more than 100,000 but when the loop hit's more than around 30000 the number of inserted items just get reduced.

so let's say if there was 100,000 items in the mysql table after complete import using the below mentioned script, i get only a maximum of 37000 or so.

My strong suscpicion is either in the node script/node mongodb connector, or some bug in the script or lastly a limit in mongodb concurrent db inserts.

I'm pasting the script below.
Hoping i get a way around it.

Thanks,

```
var http = require('http'),
  mysql = require('mysql'),
  mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  format = require('util').format;
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "xxx",
  password: "xxx",
  database: "mydb" 
});

connection.connect();
var query = "select * from mytable";
var mysqlrows = '';
connection.query(query, function(err,rows,fields){
  if(err) throw err;

  console.log(rows.length+'rows found.');

  mongo.connect('mongodb://root:root@127.0.0.1:27017/mydb', function(err, db){ 
    if (err)
      throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('mytable');
    for(var i=0; i<rows.length;i++)
    {
       //console.log(JSON.stringify(rows[i]));

      (function(i){
        collection.insert(rows[i],function(err,docs){});
        console.log(i);
      })(i);
    }

    db.close();        
  });    
});
connection.end();
```

Comment: `insert` can take an array of docs; have you tried just passing `rows` into `insert` directly instead of one by one?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i tried removing the loop and then tried inserting  the whole "rows" array itself. It does work as you say, but here again, there is a problem. If the "rows" array has a count of <1150 it works flawlessly, but if the rows count goes >1200 or so according to my testing, it fails again. Something is terribly wrong  in the method to insert large number of rows into mongdb concurrently. Here again I'm suspicious about some kind of mongodb multiple insert limit. But this is not mentioned in the mongo db limits document. [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not waiting for the `insert` operations to complete before closing your connection to MongoDb via the `db.close();` call.  You need to keep track of your outstanding asynchronous requests and then only call `db.close();` when they've all completed.

Comment: Thanks mate, Looks like it is, just removed `db.close()` & `connection.end()` from the code & it works fine in a round about way. But I'll update this thread with the final code which will use this concept, but still closing all the connections so that the solution becomes final.

Comment: I found using [`async.series`](https://github.com/caolan/async) quite helpful in managing database update operations, especially after reviewing this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18341176/549155) from [freakish](http://stackoverflow.com/users/645551/freakish)

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you are getting all the data from mySQL, try to access the last row. If you can get it, use the flag w and j of mongodb to make sure that each call inserts the data before moving to the next. with the w and j flag, you should consider multiple inserts by inserting multiple rows at each call using and  array.

Comment: Thanks @innospg, the mysql does return all the 100,000 rows as it's confirmed by this line `console.log(rows.length+'rows found.');` in the script. What is the w & j flag you are talking about? This specific about the nodejs driver i'm using?

Comment: w and j are the write concern parameters in the last release of mongodb. To debug your code, set the option safe to true and check the parameters err of the callback function.

Comment: Thanks I guess the mongodb node drive insert option `safe:true` is same as `w:1`. Also setting the option `j:1` ie journaling enabled, which makes write operation safe even if the mongod process fails automatically sets the `w:1` flag. For my case `j:1` flag was not of an issue which was a small import script with all counts of the items logged in the script itself. I think `j:1` option should be always a go for production insert usage.